# What data structures can I use to represent a strongly-typed 2D matrix of data in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I'm trying to represent a scoreboard for a competition and am struggling with the best data structures to use.

I have a list of `Player` objects, a list of `Round` objects, and for each combination, I need to store a `RoundScore` object (there are various parts to the score for a round).

What I'd like is some overall `Scoreboard` object where the following holds:

1 - I can access a collection of `RoundScore` objects identified by `Round` keys by providing a `Player` object. For example, maybe something like:

```
public IDictionary<Round,RoundScore> PlayerScores(Player player) { ... }
```

2 - I can access a collection of `RoundScore` objects identified by `Player` keys by providing a `Round` object. e.g:

```
public IDictionary<Player,RoundScore> RoundScores(Round round) { ... }
```

3 - I can access a single `RoundScore` object by providing a `Player` and a `Round`

4 - I can add a new `Round` and all `Players` will get a new `RoundScore` for that round with default values

5 - Similarly, I can add a new `Player` and all `Rounds` will have a new `RoundScore` for that player with default values

---

I guess what I'm really looking for is a representation of a grid with `Rounds` on one axis, `Players` on the other, and `RoundScores` in the middle.

Is there any data structure (or combination of data structures) already in .Net that I can use for this or will I have to roll my own?

Comment: You can add a new Player who will have a score in every round : will you will also need to deal with a case of a Round in which one or more Players are absent : (i.e., one might be kicked out of the game, another sidelined by injury, another one might have substituted for another, etc.) ? imho it's good to explicitly define the most frequent types of access to the data up front : so you optimize for those types of access. If you are going to get thousands of requests for a total score per player, but few requests for who played in a given round, imho, that should influence design. best,

Comment: If a player is absent for a round, there are rules that set the values in that player's `RoundScore` for that round.  In other words, there will be no missing entries in this *Matrix*  The most frequent operations will be constructing this object from entries in the database, and turning the object into an HTML table.  I don't need to handle substitutions, and I'm talking about < 100 players with < 100 rounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll have to roll your own. You could store your matrix of data in one of these:

```
List<List<RoundScore>>
```

Then in Round, add a field that stores the index of that Round's scores.
Likewise, in Player, add a field for that player's scores.

If the rows are the scores for a round, then returning that list is trivial. To return the list of scores for a player, you could create a class that implements IList, which knows how to access the scores by index. By doing this, you don't have to copy the scores into a new list each time they are requested.

For example:

```
List<Player> Players;
List<Round> Rounds;
List<List<RoundScore>> Scores;


List<RoundScore> GetRoundScores(Round round)
{
    return Scores[round.Index];
}

IList<RoundScore> GetRoundScores(Player player)
{
    return new PlayerScoreList(Scores, player.Index); // or better yet, cache this
}


public class PlayerScoreList : IList<RoundScore>
{
    private List<List<RoundScore>> _scores;
    private int _playerIndex;

    public RoundScore this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _scores[_playerIndex][index];
        }
        set
        {
            _scores[_playerIndex][index] = value;
        }
    }

    public PlayerScoreList(List<List<RoundScore>> scores, int playerIndex)
    {
        _scores = scores;
        _playerIndex = playerIndex;
    }

    public void Add(RoundScore item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(RoundScore item)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            if (this[i].Equals(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _scores[0].Count; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<RoundScore> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            yield return this[i];
        }
    }

    // ... more methods

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like what you're doing, but the return values I get back are just going to be a list of scores rather than a dictionary.  It looks like your code should be easy to modify to get that for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You could easily implement an IDictionary the same way as the IList.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public List<Player> Players;
    public List<Round> Rounds;
    public Dictionary<Tuple<Player, Round>, RoundScore> RoundScores;
}
```